# jquery not working while using <form> tag

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Jquery is not wrking when I am using form tag in asp.net controls.so whats the solution .I am trying multiple techniques but it does not work.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#bt1").click(function () {
                $("#p1").hide(2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p runat="server" id="p1">this is asp.net</p>
        <asp:Button ID="bt1" Text="click" runat="server"/>
    </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you have a look at the generated html.... also check the browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: What does ` runat="server"` do?

Comment: runat="server" means that element is run at server side.

Comment: Please extract the generated HTML and post as an update to your question.

Comment: is it working when you remove the form?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ASP.NET and `bt1` is a [button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) server control you need to use [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx).

`<%= bt1.ClientID %>` will Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

*Use*

```
$("#<%= bt1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $("#<%= p1.ClientID %>").hide(2000);
});
```

*OR*

You can use [`ClientIDMode.Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) mode then you can continue with your existing code. However I will not recommend it.

Comment: @soravSingh, did you used `$("#<%= bt1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
  $("#<%= p1.ClientID %>").hide(2000);
 });`?